# pls-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure 'pr_1' on VB.Net OracleCommand

Tags: asp.net, oracle, vb.net, stored-procedures

We have a VB.Net class that access an Oracle stored procedure.
Its goal is to get a simple set that could be moved to a list of String.
We're getting this error:

```
pls-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure 'pr_1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignore
```

For now the VB.Net class does like this:

```
    Try
        Dim int_key As Integer = 8 
        Dim cnnctn As New OracleConnection
        Dim cmmnd  As New OracleCommand
        With cmmnd
            .Connection = cnnctn
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "pk_1.pr_1"
            .Parameters.Add("@wp_subtype_1", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = int_key
            Dim ret_PR As New OracleParameter("@wp_tab_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
            .Parameters.Add(ret_PR)
            .Parameters.Add("@wp_cd_err" , OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output).Size = 5
            .Parameters.Add("@wp_msg_err", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output).Size = 250
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            If CInt(.Parameters("@wp_cd_erro").Value.ToString()) <> 0 Then
                'TODO : error handling'
            End If
```

The prodecure's SPEC is like this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE pk_1 AS
    TYPE rc_cursor  IS REF CURSOR;
    SUBTYPE subtype_1  IS PLS_INTEGER RANGE 1..10 NOT NULL;
    TYPE tp_tb_rslt  IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(7);
-- ...   
   PROCEDURE pr_1 (
   wp_subtype_1    IN       subtype_1
 , wp_tab_result   OUT      tp_tb_rslt
 , wp_cd_err       OUT      NUMBER
 , wp_msg_err      OUT      VARCHAR2) ;
END pk_1;
```

If the error mentions the first line of the procedure I think the problem is in the the class. Maybe in the match of the OracleDbType with the subtype of the procedure...

Any tips on how to debug this will be helpful!

Comment: I think syntax `"@wp_subtype_1"` is used for SQL-Server. Try `"wp_subtype_1"` or `":wp_subtype_1"`

Comment: I use @ because we have previous classes with this sintax. I'm adding a new one similar to the existing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if subtypes are supported by VB.NET. Perhaps try simple `INTEGER` data type.

You can use only Associative Array, see [PL/SQL Associative Array Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB)

Should be like this:

```
TYPE tp_tb_rslt  IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(7) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

...

par = cmmnd.Parameters.Add("wp_tab_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
par.Size = 10
par.Value = DBNull.Value
.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Then you can loop over the result. However, instead of PLSQLAssociativeArray output parameter, I would recommend a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. Handling should be easier and you will also fine more examples in the WWW.

The [Provider for OLE DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLEDB/using.htm#OLEDB003) may also help. Perhaps the OLE DB provider does not support User-Defined-Types and/or PL/SQL-Arrays.